# getting missing artifact jar error while building springboot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar

i am getting this missing artifact error while trying to build my springboot app
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZrl.png)

i have updated my maven , clean, uodated , installed the project buut nothing is happening , i have build this project before and it was building just fine .[my pom xml [my pom xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaMTk.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtR11.jpg)

Comment: you are using Taxian-admin as a dependency in your project. Have you build Taxian-admin already?